# How to subtract two days from a date in Java?

Tags: java, date

```
    String dateSample = "2016-09-30 21:59:22.2500000";

    String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    String newFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(newFormat);

    sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(dateSample));
```

From this, I got 09-30-2016
But, I want the result 09-28-2016
How to do it?

Comment: use calendar instance

Comment: If you put Sep 30th in, why would you expect it to return Sep 28th? I assume you are asking how to subtract two days from the Date?

Comment: I suggest you use JSR-310 DataTiIme library added in Java 8 (with a back port to Java 6)

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( sdf1.parse(dateSample));
cal.add( GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2); // date manipulation
System.out.println(sdf2.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Hope I helped

Comment: Thank You... It's working as expected.

Comment: FYI, these notoriously troublesome classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.